# what's difference between ModalBottomSheetLayout and BottomSheetScaffold in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Simple question, what's difference between ModalBottomSheetLayout and BottomSheetScaffold in compose?
if they both do the same things so what's the difference ?

Comment: BottomSheetScaffold provides slot API, you would normally see it on Maps app where's the sheet can't be collapsed entirely.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

there are several differences.

1. **ModalBottomSheetLayout** is a **modal window** that does not allow you to interact with the rest of the screen. It will collapse if you touch the dimmed part of the screen. **BottomSheetScaffold** allows you to interact with the rest of the screen. **BottomSheetScaffold** allows you to keep the bottomSheet on the screen all the time. You can even disable gestures and don't allow users to close it. And you can add a peekHeight to make the bottomSheet visible even in collapsed state.
2. **ModalBottomSheetLayout** creates a shadow above the rest of the screen, but it leaves a status bar unchanged (unlike BottomSheetDialogFragment which dims the status bar with the rest of the screen). **BottomSheetScaffold** does not dim the screen.
3. As people already said **BottomSheetScaffold** provides the Slot API, it is a container. You can add a TopAppBar, a DrawerContent, a SheetContent, a Floating Action Button and a Snackbar. **ModalBottomSheet** contains only bottomSheet content and the rest of the screen.

So these components have different use cases.

**ModalBottomSheetLayout** is a modal window that can be used to ask user for a **one-time action** that requires immediate attention

and **BottomSheetScaffold** is a container that allows you to create a bottomSheet that makes **continuous interaction with the content** possible, for example you can add a textField to enter messages or a voice input button

Hope somebody will find my definitions useful :)

Answer (score 0):

BottomSheetScaffold has no BottomAppBar property

ModalBottomSheetLayout has only content and sheetContent

which in another way to say, ModalBottomSheetLayout is able to be full screen

Comment: BottomSheetScaffold can also be full screen.